# What is the insight behind the usual proof of Taylor's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

I am currently studying the book,

> Elementary Analysis: The theory of Calculus (Kenneth A.Ross)

In the section of Taylor's Theorem, it states:
[image]
The proof was given directly after:
[image]
This proof is direct and natural, as I can kinda understand how the proof is thought up.

However, the book stated that it isn't the usual proof,
[image][image]

I understand each step of the step, but when I then try to get a general sense of the proof, I was confused. The proof sounds weird, at least to me. Of course it get me to the result, but I don't know how the author of the proof ever thought up the idea.

Below are what I have tried:

In the proof, $$F(t)=f(x)-R_n(f,t,x)+\frac{M(x-t)^n}{n!}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$$
,while $R_n(f,t,x)$ is the $n$-th remainder of taylor series expansion of $f$ about centre $t$, evaluate at $x$, so by $(1)$,
$$F(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^k+\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}[M-f^{(n)}(t)]$$

So what I think the insight is:

We want a function $F$ on $(a,b)$ such that $F(0)=F(x)$,
If $x=0$, $$F(0)=f(x)=f(x)-R_n(f,0,x)+\frac{M(x-0)^n}{n!}$$
So we observe that we may make $F$ in terms of the centre of Taylor series, i.e. variable $t$. So we (guess?) the definition of $F$.

I does not safisfy the explanation, can anyone give an explanation of the deep insight of the proof of the Taylor's Theorem?

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2715363/understanding-cauchy-mean-value-theorem/2715427#2715427). Using integration by parts recursively and a mean value theorem for integrals we achieve this result.

Comment: this proof seems *ad-hoc*. There are, unfortunately, many unsatisfying *ad-hoc* proofs in the literature. The "insight" here is just build some $F$ to apply Rolle's theorem, that is, that $F(x)=F(0)$.